# What Scala project provides the @data macro?

Tags: scala, macros, case-class

Simple question, but I'm having trouble getting the answer via Google. I've seen in the past that someone wrote a macro to let you opt-in to the various things `case class` gives you, which you get by adding the `@data` macro annotation to a `class`, instead of the `case` keyword. What project is this?

Comment: I would go to the Scala gitter channel and ask this question there. It's off-topic as you're asking someone to find a resource for you offsite.

Answer (score 1):

I think this was part of a workshop on Scala macros.

> Exercise material for Scala World 2016 talk "Return of the Scala Compiler Plugin"

https://github.com/fommil/scala-compiler-plugin

This project contains a `@data` macro to simulate case classes, written by Sam Halliday with some pending pull request by Eugene Burmako.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this from https://github.com/alexarchambault/data-class.

The usage looks like:

```scala
import dataclass.data

@data class Foo(n: Int, s: String)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that `@data class`. And I can't imagine someone to do it, there's no advantage over case class. you have to type more, and I would trust more in the native implementation over some lib

I think you are referring to project lombok (that is meant to Java, but probably can be used on Scala): https://projectlombok.org/features/Data.html

Also, Kotlin has `data class` instead of `case class`: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html

Comment: The idea is that it allows you to select which of the `case class` features you want, rather than the "take it or leave it" approach of the `case` keyword. This might be useful if you don't want the default `apply`, for example, but you want the rest of the behavior.